# Disable docview in emacs-w3m

Tags: emacs

How can I disable docview in `emacs-w3m`?

I want to open an Internet `pdf` file in `xpdf` or just download it. I don't want it to open in docview.

Answer (score 0):

if you meet the same issue while directly opening a pdf, most probably openwith is what you are looking to : http://www.emacswiki.org/OpenWith.